# CoreML and YOLOv3 performance issue

Tags: objective-c, macos, yolo, coreml

currently I am facing issue with performance of YOLOv3 implemented in objective-c/C++ XCode project for MacOS, however the performance is too slow. I do not have much experience with MacOS and XCode so I followed [this](https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/userguide/object_detection/export-coreml.html) tutorial. The execution time is around ~0.25 second.

**Setup:**
I run it on **MacBook Pro Intel Core i5 3.1 GHz and graphic Intel Iris Plus Graphic 650 1536MB** and the performance is around 4 fps. That's understandable, the GPU is not powerful one and it uses mostly CPU. Accually, it is impresive because it is faster than Pytorch implementation running on CPU. However, I run this example on MacBook pro **Intel i7 2.7GHz and AMD Radeon Pro 460** and the performance is only 6 fps.

By [this](https://github.com/tucan9389/ObjectDetection-CoreML) website the performance should be much better. Can you please let me know where I am doing mistake or it the best performance I can get with this setup? Please note that I've checked system monitor and GPU is fully used in both cases.

This is my initialisation:

```
//loading model
MLModel *model_ml = [[[YOLOv3 alloc] init] model];

float confidencerThreshold = 0.8;
NSMutableArray<Prediction*> *predictions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

VNCoreMLModel *model = [VNCoreMLModel modelForMLModel:model_ml error:nil];

VNCoreMLRequest *request = [[VNCoreMLRequest alloc] initWithModel:model completionHandler:^(VNRequest * _Nonnull request, NSError * _Nullable error){
    for(VNRecognizedObjectObservation *observation in request.results)
    {
        if(observation.confidence > confidencerThreshold){
            CGRect rect = observation.boundingBox;
            Prediction* prediction = [[Prediction alloc] initWithValues: 0 Confidence: observation.confidence BBox: rect];
            [predictions addObject:prediction];
        }
    }
}];

request.imageCropAndScaleOption = VNImageCropAndScaleOptionScaleFill;

float ratio = height/CGFloat(width);
```

And my loop implementation

```
cv::Mat frame;
int i = 0;
while(1){

    cap>>frame;

    if(frame.empty()){
        break;
    }

    image = CGImageFromCVMat(frame.clone());
     VNImageRequestHandler *imageHandler = [[VNImageRequestHandler alloc] initWithCGImage:image options:nil];

    NSDate *methodStart = [NSDate date];    //Measuring performance here

    NSError *error = nil;
    [imageHandler performRequests:@[request] error:&error];    //Call request

    if(error){
        NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
    }

    NSDate *methodFinish = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval executionTime = [methodFinish timeIntervalSinceDate:methodStart];  //get execution time

    // draw bounding boxes
    for(Prediction *prediction in predictions){
        CGRect rect = [prediction getBBox];
        cv::rectangle(frame,cv::Point(rect.origin.x * width,(1 - rect.origin.y) * height),
                      cv::Point((rect.origin.x + rect.size.width) * width, (1 - (rect.origin.y + rect.size.height)) * height),
                      cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 1,8,0);
    }

    std::cout<<"Execution time "<<executionTime<<" sec"<<" Frame id: "<<i<<" with size "<<frame.size()<<std::endl;
    [predictions removeAllObjects];

}
cap.release();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint on the line that calls `[imageHandler performRequests]` and run the app with optimizations disabled. Use the "Step Into" button from the debugger a number of times. Look in the stacktrace for "Espresso".

Does this show something like `Espresso::BNNSEngine`? Then the model runs on the CPU, not the GPU.

Does the stacktrace show something like `Espresso::MPSEngine`? Then you're running on the GPU.

My guess is Core ML runs your model on the CPU, not on the GPU.

Comment: I'll check it out. At the beginnig of program I got `[espresso] [Espresso::handle_ex_] exception=Unsupported engine` type but I didn't pay attention to that. Maybe it is related.

Comment: With `request.usesCPUOnly = true;` it's running 2 fps and my cpu is burning. I don't think so there's the problem.

Comment: All right, that rules this out as a potential issue. :-) Note that the website you linked to as "the performance should be much better" only gives numbers for iOS devices. Don't be fooled into thinking that a Mac should give better performance than an iOS device!